# Альтернатива fetch_all в mysqli

Tags: mysqli, php

Всем привет! В своем проекте я использую mysqli и для выбора всех вариантов использую fetch_all. Но у хостера не поддерживается библиотека mysqli, предложили мне воспользоваться следующим решением (НЕ РЕКЛАМА http://goo.gl/KgtPRl). Структура кода проста, но я не понимаю, как мне мою заменить на вышепривиденную? Мой код

```
public function all_fetch_array() {
    return $this->result->fetch_all();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я советую написать в поддержку хостинга и попросить добавить MySQLi. Я не думаю, что они будут против.

И вообще это очень возмутительно, что на хостинге отсутствует MySQLi, вас это не наталкивает на мысль о смене хостинг-провайдера?

Comment: @Bastian пробовал, посоветовали перейти на VPS. Кстати, хостинг очень популярный — R*G.RU.
Очень много сайтов там размещено, муторно. Хочется попробовать без этого.

Comment: @Lektor, я тоже за VPS, только, наверное, не у рег.ру

Comment: @Etki т.е без этого проблему не решить?

Comment: Рег.ру как хостер, очень даже отстойно :) в интернете большое множество отличных хостинг провайдеров.

Comment: @Lektor можно взять другого хостера и продолжить жить на shared, почему бы и нет.